# How do i delete faces and keep faces next to deleted faces smooth?

Tags: modeling

Basically I am trying to delete faces from a place and doing so either by selecting deleting faces only or disolve faces makes the faces around the now deleted faces unsmooth and jagged.

Is there a way i can delete current faces, but keep faces around the deleted faces smooth?

[This is the gif of the problem i have](https://imgur.com/a/cpDFK)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding the extra loopcuts at the edge. Select the whole mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> and get rid of tris with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Add two loopcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and place them very close to the edge. Then triangulate the mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. 
[image]

Result:
[image]
[image]

If you don't want to add extra geometry as above just check the **Autosmooth** checkbox in a *Mesh Data* header.
[image]

Comment: So, what does triangulation do to the mesh in this case?

Comment: its just because your Mesh was Triangulated but in general you should use Quads with the Subdivision Modifier